# Physics update in cocos2d-x v3

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, game-physics, chipmunk, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm developing a game, using cocos2d-x 3.1.1 on Linux, that is going to have physics support.
I'm still at at the basics, but I'm already having many headaches.
The posted code is essentially what i have done so far, a ball influenced by gravity and a random velocity vector.

The problem is the simulation seems to never start, even if the sprite is rendered correctly. The ball does not move, in fact the position of the body is always the same (i log it). I tried to debug the application and to move blocks of code in other functions, without results.

Menu.cpp

```
#include "Menu.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define COCOS2D_DEBUG 1
USING_NS_CC;


ScenaMenu *ScenaMenu::createWithPhysics() {

ScenaMenu *ret = new ScenaMenu();
if (ret && ret->initWithPhysics()) {
    ret->autorelease();
    return ret;
}
else {
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(ret);
    return nullptr;
    }


}


ScenaMenu::ScenaMenu() {

    frameSize = Director::getInstance()->getOpenGLView()->getFrameSize();

}



ScenaMenu::~ScenaMenu() {}



void ScenaMenu::onEnter() {

Scene::onEnter();

fisica = this->getPhysicsWorld();
fisica->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);
fisica->setGravity(Vec2(0, -10.0f));

Texture2D::TexParams texParams = { GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE };
LayerColor *layerMenu = LayerColor::create(Color4B(255, 255, 255, 255));
layerMenu->setContentSize(frameSize);

textureSfera = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage("sfera2.png");
textureSfera->setTexParameters(&texParams);
textureSfera->generateMipmap();

float angolo;
srand(time(NULL));
PhysicsMaterial mat = PhysicsMaterial(1, 1, 0);
PhysicsBody *bodyFisica; 

bodyFisica = PhysicsBody::createCircle(layerMenu->getContentSize().width * 0.1, mat, Vec2::ZERO);
angolo = (rand() % 628) / 100.0f;
bodyFisica->setVelocity(Vec2(10 * cos(angolo), 10 * sin(angolo)));

spriteSfera = Sprite::createWithTexture(textureSfera);
spriteSfera->setScale((layerMenu->getContentSize().width * 0.33) / spriteSfera->getContentSize().width);
spriteSfera->setPosition(layerMenu->getContentSize().width * 0.5, layerMenu->getContentSize().height * 0.5);
spriteSfera->setPhysicsBody(bodyFisica);


this->addChild(layerMenu);

layerMenu->addChild(spriteSfera);

}


void ScenaMenu::update(float dt) {

log("POS %f", spriteSfera->getPhysicsBody()->getPosition().y);

}
```

AppDelegate.cpp

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "Menu.h"

USING_NS_CC;

AppDelegate::AppDelegate() {

}

AppDelegate::~AppDelegate() 
{
}

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() {

    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();

if(!glview) {
        glview = GLView::create("Test");
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
}

Size frameSize = Size(540, 960);
cocos2d::Size designResolutionSize = Size(1080, 1920);

glview->setDesignResolutionSize(designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height, ResolutionPolicy::FIXED_WIDTH);
glview->setFrameSize(frameSize.width, frameSize.height);

director->setDisplayStats(true);

director->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);

ScenaMenu *scenaMenu = ScenaMenu::createWithPhysics();
director->runWithScene(scenaMenu);

    return true;
}

// This function will be called when the app is inactive. When comes a phone call,it's be invoked too
void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    Director::getInstance()->stopAnimation();

    // if you use SimpleAudioEngine, it must be pause
    // SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
}

// this function will be called when the app is active again
void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    Director::getInstance()->startAnimation();

    // if you use SimpleAudioEngine, it must resume here
    // SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->resumeBackgroundMusic();
}
```

Comment: I think you have to manually step the world every update, ie something like this->getPhysicsWorld()->Step(); (see class references/manual for actual method name/params)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I thought this was automatically done by the Scene after you initWithPhysics() it. In fact, i didn't find anything about needing it in the documentation (not that cocos2d-x' docs are something special...). Also all the update functions of PhysicsWorld are protected

Comment: Not sure about v3 it may have been done automatically like in cocos2d-iphone but I couldn't find anything related to physics being built-in in the class reference.

Comment: From http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Physics :
"In cocos2d-x v3+ things have changed. Cocos2d-x v3+ integrates a new physics engine, based on Chipmunk into the core API. Developers no longer need to be concerned about which physics engine will be used or need to call the physics engine API directly."
So yeah, it should do everything automatically

Comment: Try calling Scene:update() method in your ScenaMenu::update(). Probably you have overrided update so that parent's method is not called.

Comment: @Nadarian you are the best person in the world. Thank you